# OpenGl - texture on glutSolidSphere does not show

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures, glut

i have managed to load texture

```
// Load texture
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);



    pBytes = gltLoadTGA("../earth.tga", &iWidth, &iHeight, &iComponents, &eFormat);     
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, iComponents, iWidth, iHeight, 0, eFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBytes);
    free(pBytes);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
```

when i texture the sphere like this it does not show (image 256x256 32bit)

```
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glutSolidSphere(35.0f, 30, 17); 
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

but i have a ship made out of a pyramid shape the same technique works on it

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    ship(); 
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

anyone any idea why this is happening please...(please don't mark me down i'm working hard here)

Comment: You may have to provide more context here - where do you allocate the texture and where do you bind it?

Comment: im new to this not sure what u mean... this all the code i have on texture tbh

Comment: Is there something different in the `ship()` function that makes it work? Did you use `glBindTexture` to select the texture? You may find this tutorial on OpenGL textures useful: http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html

Comment: ill check that out but have i loaded the texture correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have loaded the texture image. But you also need to supply texture coordinates. Your ship may do this. glutSolidSphere however does not, and there's nothing you can do about it. So don't use glutSolidSphere.

Comment: im not... im using gluShpere... but the sphere its self is tilted not texture

Comment: The title says glutSolidSphere. Anyway, GLU Quadrics, i.e. gluSphere doesn't produce texture coordiates as well, if not enabled. Zou must call `gluQuadricTexture(quadric, GL_TRUE);` to enable texture coordinate generation.

Comment: oh yeah sorry wrong question i am using gluSphere now but i did it thanks mate lol